# script in div container

Tags: r, shiny

Edit: Based on the comment added "". The code works now.

I am trying to embed a 3D mol viewer in my shiny app as described here:
http://3dmol.csb.pitt.edu/doc/tutorial-embeddable.html

I tried the following code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
         tags$head(HTML('<script src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js"></script>')),
         tags$div(
                  style="height: 400px; width: 400px; position: relative;",
                  class='viewer_3Dmoljs',
                  'data-pdb' ='1YCR',
                  'data-backgroundcolor' ='0xffffff',
                  'data-style' ='stick'
                  ))
         )
        )

 server <- function(input, output) {


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It look like the data-pdb, data-backgroundcolor and data-style are not recognized. If I remove these arguments I get a black box. Anybody knows how I could get this working? Also, would it be possible to direct the load-pdb to a local file?

Comment: Doesn't this return a syntax error for you? You need to put names that have dashes ("-") in them inside quotes. For example `'data-pdb'='1YCR',` etc

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. Can't believe I did not see that!